# ¿Por qué me sigue indicando Success?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estoy haciendo un sistema de registro, y estoy utilizando SweetAlert2 para indicar que la cuenta fue registrada y eso. El caso es que al verificar que la cuenta no exista, me la sigue marcando como success en lugar de error, esta es la parte que utilizo en "register.php"

```php
$(function(){
        $('#register').click(function(e){
            var valid = this.form.checkValidity();
            if(valid){
            var nombre  = $('#nombre').val();
            var email       = $('#email').val();
            var password    = $('#password').val();

                e.preventDefault(); 
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'process.php',
                    data: {nombre: nombre,email: email,password: password},
                    success: function(data){
                    Swal.fire({
                                'title': 'Cuenta registrada',
                                'text': data,
                                'type': 'success'
                                })

                    },
                    error: function(data){
                        Swal.fire({
                                'title': 'Error:',
                                'text': 'Ocurrió un error al guardar tu información.',
                                'type': 'error'
                                })
                    }
                });

            }else{

            }

        });     

    });
```

Y esta es la parte que utilizo para "process.php"

```php
if(isset($_POST)){
    $nombre         = $_POST['nombre'];
    $email          = $_POST['email'];
    $password       = sha1($_POST['password']);
        $ver = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM pcu_cuentas WHERE JNombre = :nombre");
        $ver->bindParam(':nombre', $nombre);
        $ver->execute();
        if($ver->rowCount() > 0){
            echo 'Ya existe una cuenta con ese nombre, intenta otro.';
        } else {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO pcu_cuentas (JNombre, Contra, Email) VALUES (?,?,?)";
            $stmtinsert = $db->prepare($sql);
            $result = $stmtinsert->execute([$nombre, $email, $password]);
            if($result){
                echo 'Cuenta creada correctamente.';
            }else{
                echo 'Ocurrió algún error al crear la cuenta.';
            }
        }

}else{
    echo 'Sin datos...';
}
```

El caso es que en la alerta del Sweet si me indica lo del process.php "Ya existe una cuenta con ese nombre, intenta otro", pero como su fuera un success, me aparece la palomita y todo. Quiero saber como solucionar eso.
Gracias.

Comment: ¿Cómo le informas a la petición ajax cuando hay un error?

Comment: @Shaz ahí coloqué el IF completo del process.php.

Comment: Según entiendo, le «informas» a la petición AJAX con un echo. ¿Es correcto?

Comment: Así es, pero es el echo "Sin datos..."